# UIDocumentInteractionController shows "copy to" along with another entry for same app

Tags: ios, share, uidocumentinteraction, uti

I bring up a UIDocumentInteractionController like this:

```
self.documentInteractionController = [[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc] init];
    _documentInteractionController.delegate = self;
    _documentInteractionController.UTI = kUTTypeMPEG4;
    _documentInteractionController.URL = aURL;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
        [_documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:view animated:YES];
    });
```

The resulting UIDocumentInteractionController has plenty of duplicate entries.

e.g. "WhatsApp" and "Copy to WhatsApp", "Slack" and "Copy to Slack",...

Is there any configuration I have missed to avoid that?

```
[UIDocumentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:]
[UIDocumentInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:]
```

Reading the docs it seemed to me `presentOpenInMenuFromRect:` might be more limited by showing only apps capable of opening the file - but both methods show the same duplicates.

Comment: is using UIActivityViewController a viable alternative?

Comment: no I don't want to use UIActivityViewController for sharing

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? In my app actions show up such as "Copy To Evernote" and "Copy to Dropbox", but neither do anything if I click on them. I would like to remove them or figure out how to make them work.

Comment: @duncanc4 Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @dariru I ended up switching to UIActivityViewController, which seems to work better. Though I still have options like "Copy to Slack", which does launch Slack when tapped, but doesn't do anything with the CSV file I am trying to share.